# Laravel Migrations | Blueprint Class and Schema Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am new to Laravel Backend PHP Framework and recently I came to a "Blueprint" and "Schema" classes.

On top of my file I use :

```
`
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
`
```

To implement those inbuilt classes to my recently created folder and I understood that .
Well , I have been recently exploring more about this "Blueprint" class but it seems that there is not so much explanation on the internet .
There is only a Laravel's API documentation so far which does not give me a tutorial on it .

Is there any more experienced developer to explain me more this Blueprint class and Laravel's migrations in general ?

Thanks a lot .

I tried to find more information on internet but it seems that there is no such a precise and descriptive info about this topic .

Comment: The [`Blueprint` class](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html) is the one responsible for making the various Column methods available during a Migration, like `$table->increments()` comes from https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_increments, etc. Beyond that, what do you specifically need to know about these classes? The [documentation for Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations) is quite detailed and explains how they work, how to run them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Schema class is responsible for creating, altering, and dropping database tables, as well as modifying table columns, indexes, and constraints. You use the static methods of this class, such as `create()`, `table()`, and `dropIfExists()`, to define the operations you want to perform on your database.

The Blueprint class is used to define the details of the database schema modifications you want to perform. When you use the `create()` or `table()` method of the Schema class, it returns a Blueprint object that you can use to specify the columns, indexes, and constraints for the table you are creating or modifying.